# Adding a Parameter To ListView

Tags: android, listview

I'm following a tutorial on ListView. In the tutorial there is a TextView which includes the fixed word 'description' and then the subsets of the string 'country' in front of it.

I've been trying to replace it with another TextView; 'currency' instead of 'description' with each corresponding currency, but I couldn't figure out how.

Any help is appreciated

Here are the List View codes of the tutorial:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

ListView list;
String[] country={
        "France",
        "India",
        "Germany",
        "The US",
        "Japan",
        "Korea",
        "China",
        "Canada"
    };

Integer[] countryid={
        R.drawable.pic1,
        R.drawable.pic2,
        R.drawable.pic3,
        R.drawable.pic4,
        R.drawable.pic5,
        R.drawable.pic6,
        R.drawable.pic7,
        R.drawable.pic8,
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, country, countryid);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Slectedcountry= country[+position];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slectedcountry, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

CustomListAdapter.java

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] country;
private final Integer[] countryid;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] country, Integer[] countryid) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, country);

    this.context=context;
    this.country=country;
    this.countryid=countryid;
}

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    txtTitle.setText(country[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(countryid[position]);
    extratxt.setText("Description "+country[position]); //I want to replace this

    return rowView;

};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

1. add a view in the **mylist.xml**. (to view the currency)
2. in your adpater (**CustomListAdapter.java**) add a line to find/get the view (to be able to set the view item). Similar to `TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);`
3. add another line to the adapter (**CustomListAdapter.java**) to set the found view, using the new array value. Similar to `txtTitle.setText(country[position]);`
4. Amend main (**MainActivity.java**) to setup the new array value. Something like:-

   ```
   String[] currency={
       "Franc",
       "Rupee",
       "pfenning",
       "Greenback",
       "yen",
       "something",
       "something else",
       "Pound"
   };
   ```

Comment: @Student Thanks for the edit(s), Sorry can't recall your full name.

Answer (score 1):

first create a object class, which stores data like Country,image and currency.

```
public class CountryObject{

public String country_Name;
public String country_Currency;
public int country_Image;

}
```

then a create arraylist of ModelObject. `List<CountryObject> countryList= new ArrayList<CountryObject>();`

```
CountryObject object1= new CountryObject;

    object.country_Name="India";

    object.country_currency="Rupee";

    cobject.country_Image=R.drawable.pic1;

    countryList.add(object1);
```

create a similar `CountryObject` s add to arraylits. which will pass it to adapter class for bidning with listview.

```
 CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, countryList);
```

your adapter class. please use Viewholder pattern which reduces calls in getview method and which is recommended .

```
    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Activity context;
     List<CountryObject> countrylist

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, List<CountryObject> list) {


        this.context=context;
        this.countrylist=list;
    }
    @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public CountryObject getItem(int position) {

            return countrylist.get(position);
        }
     @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return countrylist!= null ? countrylist.size() : 0;
        }
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {


     final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
                holder.ivCountryImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                holder.tvCurrency = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);


                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

       holder.tvName.setText(countrylist.get(position).country_Name);
       holder.ivCountryImage.setImageResource(countrylist.get(position).country_Image);

    //holder.tvCurrency.setText("currency "+countrylist.get(position).country_Currency);
       holder.tvCurrency.setText(countrylist.get(position).country_Currency); 

        return convertView;

    }

 public class ViewHolder {

        TextView tvName, tvCurrency;
        ImageView ivCountryImage;

    }
```

}

or else you can go with ArrayAdapter with ArrayAdapter instead of String.